# Does a malware in an android phone have permission to read/modify/delete data of all the apps?

Tags: malware, mobile, android, permissions

If an android phone is infected with malware/virus, can it access all the apps with modify/delete/read permission? Isn't there any control by an app , say a bank app which can't allow to read data by any other program?
If there is a different answer for an iphone, please share it too.

Answer (score 4):

Most android malware will steal information or spam your phone with aggressive ads. But they do not necessarily modify any installed apps on the phone. If a phone is rooted, the malware can, however, uninstall apps and replace them with malicious app copies. The following link gives an overview of many of the known android malware capabilities.

http://forensics.spreitzenbarth.de/android-malware/

Answer (score 2):

**Not necessarily**
Operating systems in general and Android specifically, implement a privilege model to access data (When you install an app, you can decide which permissions you want to give it. You can also edit those permission later on). If an application is taken over by a malicious piece of code, it will have the same privilege level as the affected application.
If the affected app has permissions to read file content, the malware can definitely access some data of other applications (For e.g. file explorer applications cans show you your whatsapp photos). It is a good practice for applications to avoid storing sensitive data in files but if they do have to, then encrypt it.
Of-course, all of this doesn't stop the malware from exploiting a vulnerability to gain root privileges but that is a different issue.